# Next.js GraphQl Blog Post Details not rendering

Tags: next.js, graphql

can anyone help to correct my code, im building a Nextjs blog website, there's 2 types of link for blog details page, one is /posts/{postId} in my home page  (http://localhost:3000/posts/1), another is /posts/{slug} which is implemented using graphql in user profile page (http://localhost:3000/posts/8-tips-using-github), the /posts/{postId} is working fine but the /posts/{slug} is not, when i click on the posts for one of the /posts/{slug}, its not redirecting me to the correct blog details page which is , its redirecting me to the /posts/{postId} details page which is , that is not correct and im not sure why is it like this, i have implemented both  and  in the [postId].js

```
code:
import Format from "../../layout/format";
import Author from "../../components/_child/author";
import Image from "next/image";
import getPost from "../../lib/helper";
import fetcher from "../../lib/fetcher";
import Spinner from "../../components/_child/spinner";
import ErrorComponent from "../../components/_child/error";
import Related from "@/components/_child/related";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { SWRConfig } from "swr";
import { GraphQLClient, gql } from "graphql-request";
import useSWR from "swr";
import styles from "@/styles/Slug.module.css";

const graphcms = new GraphQLClient(process.env.GRAPHCMS_ENDPOINT);

const QUERY = gql`
  query Post($slug: String!) {
    post(where: { slug: $slug }) {
      id,
      title,
      slug,
      datePublished,
      author {
        id
        name
        avatar {
          url
        }
      }
      content {
        html
      }
      coverPhoto {
        url
      }
    }
  }
`;

const SLUGLIST = gql`
  {
    posts {
      slug
    }
  }
`;

export default function Page({ fallback }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { postId, slug } = router.query;
  const { data, isLoading, isError } = useSWR(
    slug ? `/api/posts/${slug}` : `/api/posts/${postId}`,
    async (url) => {
      if (slug) {
        const data = await graphcms.request(QUERY, { slug });
        return data.post;
      } else {
        // Fetch data from another API for postId
        const posts = await getPost(postId);
        return posts;
      }
    }
  );

  if (isLoading) return <Spinner></Spinner>;
    if (isError) return <ErrorComponent></ErrorComponent>;

    //Conditionally render the appropriate component based on whether slug or postId is present
    return (
      <SWRConfig value={{ fallback }}>
        <SWRConfig value={{ fallback }}>
          {slug ? (
            <BlogPost post={data}></BlogPost>
          ) : (
            <Article {...data}></Article>
          )}
        </SWRConfig>
      </SWRConfig>
    );
}

function Article({ title, img, subtitle, description, author }) {
  return (
    <Format>
      <section className="container mx-auto md:px-2 py-16 w-3/4 sm:w-1/2">
        <div className="post py-10">
          <h1 className="font-extrabold text-4xl text-center text-indigo-700 pb-5">
            {title || "No Title"}
          </h1>

          <p className="text-gray-500 text-xl text-center">
            {subtitle || "No Title"}
          </p>

          <div className="flex justify-center">
            {author ? <Author {...author}></Author> : <></>}
          </div>

          <div className="py-10">
            <Image src={img || "/"} width={900} height={600} alt=""></Image>
          </div>

          <div className="content text-black text-lg flex flex-col gap-4">
            {description &&
              description
                .split("\n")
                .map((paragraph, index) => <p key={index}>{paragraph}</p>)}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <div className="mx-auto w-3/4">
        <Related></Related>
      </div>
    </Format>
  );
}


function BlogPost({ post }) {
  return (
    <main className={styles.blog}>
      <img
        className={styles.cover}
        src={post.coverPhoto.url}
        alt={post.title}
      />
      <div className={styles.title}>
        <div className={styles.authdetails}>
          <img src={post.author.avatar.url} alt={post.author.name} />
          <div className={styles.authtext}>
            <h6>By {post.author.name} </h6>
            <h6 className={styles.date}>
              {moment(post.datePublished).format("MMMM d, YYYY")}
            </h6>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2>{post.title}</h2>
      </div>

      <div
        className={styles.content}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content.html }}
      ></div>
    </main>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const postId = params.postId;

  if (params.slug) {
    const slug = params.slug;
    const data = await graphcms.request(QUERY, { slug });
    const post = data.post;

    return {
      props: {
        fallback: {
          "/api/posts": null,
        },
        post,
      },
      revalidate: 10,
    };
  } else {
    // Fetch post data from another API for postId
    const posts = await getPost(postId);

    return {
      props: {
        fallback: {
          "/api/posts": posts || null,
        },
      },
      revalidate: 10,
    };
  }
}


export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const posts = await getPost();
  const { posts: graphcmsPosts } = await graphcms.request(SLUGLIST);

  const paths = posts
    .map((value) => {
      return {
        params: {
          postId: value.id.toString(),
        },
      };
    })
    .concat(graphcmsPosts.map((post) => ({ params: { postId: post.slug } })));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

im using graphcms for the profile page, so the profile page contains graphql blog posts

Comment: How does the router distinguish a slug from an id?